# Ports needed to open for Azure app deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

We have a azure app service behind the firewall. We are using self hosted agent outside the firewall. What are the ports needs to be opened for deployment?

I have 3 options in the WebApp deployment?

1. msdeploy
2. zipdeploy
3. runfromPackage

Is it the same port used for all the deployment types?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A list of the relevant ports can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#app-service-ports